# Why would the requestTimeout option give an error when seconds are specified?

Tags: httpplatformhandler

I am finding that if requestTimeout is set to a value with seconds, the client app gets an immediate Bad Gateway error. For example requestTimeout="00:02:30". If I use whole minutes it works as expected. The app I am running is written in PowerBuilder (a desktop language similar to VB6) and uses Winsock functions directly to accept and service requests.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

The documentation Microsoft provides doesn't give much detail so I'm guessing it is hh:mm:ss. I've found other minor issues like using the wrong message number when writing to the event log and not passing the REMOTE_ADDR or REMOTE_HOST as environment variables. With the documentation being so poor I have to assume they aren't actively maintaining it. There doesn't appear to be an open source alternative either.